# merge tables from two backup files - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I have two .bak files

These files contain different tables in them, and it is guaranteed that indexing is consistent across both files

I can easily restore database A from A.bak and have tables a1, a2, a3 and likewise table B from B.bak with tables b1, b2, b3

What I really want is to restore database AB from both A.bak and B.bak and have the resulting database contain table a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Thanks!

Greg

Comment: What version (and Edition) of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there's no means for combining the .bak files - you have to restore them into separate databases before you can merge the data into a single database.

Comment: +1 for correctness; it should also be noted that t-sql DDL and some DML + sql agent or task scheduler can quite easily be used to schedule the desired behavior to occur

Answer (score 1):

You could potentitally:

- restore database A
- use Red Gate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm) to join in the tables and other db objects from the database B backup file
- use Red Gate's [SQL Data Compare][2] to join in the data from the database B backup file

The Red Gate tools are pretty nifty that way since you can compare (and sync!) a live database against a standard SQL Server backup file (requires the Pro editions of the tools).

Comment: If these databases are very large, you may find that you get significant performance gains if you use Red Gate's SQL Virtual Restore rather than SQL Data Compare Pro directly on the Backup File. http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_virtual_restore/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to restore them and merge them in one step, but you could create an agent job to temporarily restore, run a SSIS package to merge them, then drop them.